# Get the value of a BasicDatePicker with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a Basic Date picker and i would like to get its value in a JavaScript method.  No matter what i try it says undefined is the value.  Here is my code that i am using.

```
                                        <BDP:BasicDatePicker runat="server" ID="bdpToDate" TextBoxStyle-Width="62px" DateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy">
                                        </BDP:BasicDatePicker>
```

and in the javascript method.....

```
        var toDate = document.getElementById('<%=bdpToDate.ClientID %>').selectedDate;// does not work
```

also i have tried using .selectedText and .Value behind the getElementById method and neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value` (note v should be lower case)

```
var toDate = document.getElementById('<%=bdpToDate.ClientID %>_TextBox').value;
```

Comment: The .value did not work either, it still shows up as undefined when i display it back.

Comment: Can you add this statement `alert(document.getElementById('<%=bdpToDate.ClientID %>').tagName);`before the `var toDate` and let me know what is returned?

Comment: Theres an Alert box that just says DIV

Comment: I updated the answer. Did you try that? `var toDate = document.getElementById('<%=bdpToDate.ClientID %>_TextBox').value;`

Comment: WHOA......all of a sudden it opened up a screen after i clicked the OK button and it showed the date!

Comment: @Lucas: Cool, now remove the alert statement.